# Can Sockets in be closed in any other way except for socket.close()?

Tags: java, sockets

I just want to clear a doubt that I've been harboring for quite some time now: Is it possible for sockets in Java to be closed even if the `.close()` method hasn't been called in the code?

Comment: on `System.exit()`, or can be automatically closed using `try-with-resources`

Comment: Good question. What happens if you for instance close the input and output stream of the socket? Would that be equivalent to closing the socket?

Comment: please define *closed* `Socket.isClosed()` will only return true if `Socket.close()`has been called before.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Closing either the input or the output stream of the socket closes the other stream and the socket.

Comment: Is this answer implementation dependent? Or can you give a reference to the documentation?

Comment: It is not implementation dependent. My reference is the clear statements in the Javadoc.

Answer (score 1):

This code below is in **java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl**

```
/**
 * Cleans up if the user forgets to close it.
 */
protected void finalize() throws IOException {
    close();
}
```

finalize() gets called when the garbage collector is run. So if you lose all references to your Socket, it will be closed. You shouldn't do this though, as it's bad practice - you never know when the garbage collector will run, so the socket could stay open for awhile. I don't really know if this counts as it does call close() underneath. Closing input, and output streams are different that the socket. I don't think they really count.

Comment: Closing input or output steams closes the socket. No difference from this point of view.